# Why my Android app targeted to distribute in one country is downloaded in several?

Tags: android, google-play

I've published 6 apps on Play Store during the last year, all of them **targeted to distribute just in my country** under *Pricing & Distributing* section in Developer Console. Nevertheless today I was checking the contry statistics (*CURRENT INSTALLS BY DEVICE BY COUNTRY*) **and all of them have a bunch of installs in different countries** (ten or more). How is it possible?

And I know the distribution filter is working somehow, because once I asked to a friend abroad to install one of my apps and he couldn't until I check his country in Pricing & Distributing section. So I don't know why

The only explanation I can think so far is that those sections are checking different properties to get the country. Maybe "distribution" only take care of the country defined by the operator, whereas the info in statistics check where is the phone now... This is not so intuitive though, and there is not clear description in Developer Console.

I've found anothear thread asking the same, but it wasn't properly answered and today is closed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008062/android-app-being-downloaded-from-non-selected-countries
User @jasonflaherty suggested the use of a modified Google Play that doesn't check the countries. This could make sense... but I would like more opinions.

Is this happening on your apps? Any idea of what's happening?

Thanks